# Getting ACPI BIOS error on booting Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, acpi, grub-efi

My laptop is dual booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. I was installing Wine on Ubuntu 18.04, but I was getting some error related to read-only file partition. I did `sudo apt update`, but I'm still getting read-only file partition and was not able to successfully update, so I decided to reboot the system, but when I did that and selected Ubuntu from the GRUB menu I was getting ACPI BIOS error and Ubuntu was unable to boot.

[image: ACPI Error1]
<sup>**ACPI error 1**</sup>

[image: ACPI Error2]
<sup>**ACPI error 2**</sup>

I am able to boot into Windows properly. I tried searching on Google. One solution was to boot into live USB and press F6 and then select `acpi=off`. When I did boot into live USB and pressed F6 nothing happened. Another solution was to edit grub with a statement like this: 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=strict"`

[image: Grub edit]
<sup>**GRUB edit**</sup>

Comment: Hi, did you solve this? Booting the liveUSB works, so I think that even if there is an hardware issue, it can bypassed by using a kernel compiled like the liveUSB one, but the question is how to do so? I also have a dual boot and Windows just works fine. So I guess linux is more strict about hardware issues and blocks the boot unnecessarily. I tried to add to GRUB these options: `nomce acpi=off` but no success, it still doesn't boot.